projection problem in berry curvature calculation using Quantum ESPRESSO
sana@sana-H81M-P33-MS-7817:~/mos2/berrynoor$ wannier90.x mos2
mos2.amn has too many projections to be used without selecting a subset
Error: examine the output/error file for details

What did the output and error files say?

[mos2.amn has too many projections to be used without selecting a subset Error: examine the output/error file for details] sir this is the error, sir i'm calculating berry-phase using Quantum Espresso & wainner90 i follow this (https://lists.quantum-espresso.org/pipermail/wannier/2018-January/001459.html). when i run mos2.win i facehis error

What I meant was that your error says: "examine the output/error file for details" , so I was asking what these files said.

1:mpirun -np 4 pw.x -inp scf.in > scf.out
2:wannier90.x -pp mos2 3:pw2wannier90.x -inp mos2.pw2wan
4:wannier90.x mos2
my error is in 4 step mos2.amn has not the right number of projections. how can i solve this error

The first thing to look at is how many bands you have and how many Wannier functions you're asking for (you can't have more Wannier centres than bands).
